# Unable to affect mesh regions with DiscretizeGraphics

Tags: graphics3d, mesh, discretization

### Problem

On the sphere, it is easy to control the resolution of the mesh in `DiscretizeGraphics` using the `MaxCellMeasure` attributes of `Length` and `Area`.

But these tricks do not seem to work on the cuboid. For example, varying the length from 1000 to 0.001 produces this same mesh.

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Graphics3D[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {50, 3, 4}]], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 10.0}]
```

[image: Mesh]

### Question

How does one control the mesh resolution in this case?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `DiscretizeRegion` since both return a `MeshRegion`? Something like `DiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {50, 3, 4}], 
 MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 10.0}]`.

Comment: @Tim Laska: This is a great start. The length decreases as expected until 3, then at 2, the mesh reverts. Can you address this and post your comment as an answer so it can be selected?

Comment: [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package can help you to precisely control the number of elements / mesh size. See the function `HexahedronMesh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `DiscretizeGraphics` and `DiscretizeRegion`  return a `MeshRegion`.  `DiscretizeRegion` is more precise.

A mesh level of "2" does not appear to work because the thickness of the lines are too faint.  One can use `HighlightMesh` to see the discretization more clearly.

```
HighlightMesh[
   DiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {50, 3, 4}], 
    MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> #}], Style[1, Red]] & /@ 
 Range[2, 10]
```

[image]